# Where can I find explicit description of reduction theory?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory

I read a book about binary quadratic forms in which the author mentioned reduction theory. I do not know where to find more description of reduction theory. I only know the reduction theory in binary quadratic forms. I really want to know what reduction theory really is.

Comment: I guess that Borel's book on arithmetic groups is a good place to start.

A more recent refernece is Witte-Morris' new book about arithmetic groups.

Comment: What do you have in mind by "explicit"?

Comment: I want some book about reduction theory which are suitable for an undergraduate majored in mathematics.

Comment: @Thea: It depends on the undergraduate, of course, but "reduction theory" in the setting of arithmetic groups is not at all elementary.    The older monograph by Borel is in French and somewhat hard going (partly because some of my proofreading corrections didn't make it into print); so it's likely that the book by Dave Witte-Morris would be a better start.  Anyway, the idea is to carry over to other semisimple groups Siegel's classical ideas of reduction theory for special orthogonal groups (via reduction for quadratic forms).

Comment: P.S.  Though I haven't spent enough time with the book to characterize what he actually does, here is an online version of it: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0106.5063

Comment: @JimHumphreys the link in [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278831/where-can-i-find-explicit-description-of-reduction-theory#comment687277_278831) is broken, a replacement is https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106063